# CoreGraphics - How do I draw rects one by one on a plane?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a sort of progress bar which is actually a visual representation of the read content of a book. This bar is a horizontal line which is filled up at areas the book was read at. As an example, if it's a 100 paged book, and the user has read only page 1 to 10 and 90 to 100, the progress bar will show the 10% area at the extreme left and 10% area at the extreme right filled with color.

I am currently using this code to draw rect for one reading session:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect innerRect = CGRectInset(rect, 5, 5);
CGRect ProgressIndicator = CGRectMake(innerRect.origin.x, innerRect.origin.y, 20, innerRect.size.height);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(ProgressIndicator), CGRectGetMinY(ProgressIndicator));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(ProgressIndicator), CGRectGetMinY(ProgressIndicator));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(ProgressIndicator), CGRectGetMaxY(ProgressIndicator));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(ProgressIndicator), CGRectGetMaxY(ProgressIndicator));
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor]CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, ProgressIndicator);
```

Now, this is just for one reading session and draws only one rect as the rectangular "read" portion on the bar. How do I manage the drawing if I have multiple rects (say in an array) to draw on the bar. I am afraid that I'll lose the current drawing once I draw another rect.

How do I use "for" loop to draw those multiple rects?

I know this might be a very dumb question but I tried finding a way around it but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest thinking about this a different way; keeping track of an arbitrary number of 'reading sessions' could be a very inefficient representation.

In situations like this rather than concatenating every time data from a 'reading session' I would suggest that a sparse representation might make your drawing easier - just keep track of which pages have been read, period, in an array or dictionary or a custom object.

Then, your drawing code could simply loop over the storage and draw a section in one color for 'read' and not draw, or draw another color, etc, for 'unread'.